# Have to always run rake assets:precompile before starting server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am not sure what I changed, but before running my Rails app, I always have to execute: `rake assets:precompile`

Or else, my coffeescript files do not get updated. How do I get Rails to automatically run this for me?

Comment: Are you running your app in production?

Comment: It's running on development

Comment: In `development.rb`, use `config.assets.compile = true` and remove all precompiled assets from public folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

**config/environments/development.rb**

```
config.serve_static_assets = false
```

Doing so,

No files from `public` folder will get served.

The other way is that you have to delete the compiled files as a second option. In development mode, you do not need to compile like that. It happens during app deployment.

Answer (score 2):

In development mode there is no need to run `$ rake assets:precompile`. They are compiled everytime when you sending request to your app. Simply remove whole `public/assets` directory and then you can update your CSS and JS on live app.